# NVDA calls out incomplete error message and twice

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, nvda, accessibility

Use case : While gift cards are applied, NVDA should read out the error message for all error scenarios like, *'The card is already redeemed'* or *'Error occurred while validating card'* etc.

Issue : After applying `code='alert'` , the error message reads out, however NVDA partially calls out the error message one additional time. Please refer the speech-viewer snippet below for the exact behavior :

> Alert Error while validating card

> Shopping cart | Page title

> clickable main landmark  validating card

Code snippet : Added `element.parent().after(error).attr("role","alert");` in the JS file.

Can anyone help me understand why and from where is the NVDA calling once again that too partially in Chrome, Firefox as well as Edge browsers.
Whereas, the same error message is being called out correctly while using the Chrome screen-reader extension in Google Chrome.[DOM structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LnqX5.png)

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to assess without a little more of the resulting markup, but one possibility is that NVDA is reading your message once as a live region and once as part of the focused element's associated label or description. It's quite common to see spotty live region behavior across browsers.

Setting role="alert" SHOULD BE equivalent to setting aria-live="assertive" and aria-atomic="true". This means that the error text should, IN THEORY, be read first (assertive) and completely (atomic). Any other announcements, such as a label, aria-label, or description of what's in focus should then proceed, and that could include the error message.

First see how it announces without the live region by removing role="alert" and any aria-live properties there.

If the focused element does not announce the error on its own, put back the role="alert" and try setting aria-atomic="true" on your alert so that all browsers read the complete text and not just the change in the text.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the response. There are no aria-live properties associated with the error message or it's parent. Even after removing the role='alert', the NVDA reads 'clickable main landmark  validating card' which is only the partial error message. However, the first occurrence of the error message with an 'alert' concatenated to it gets omitted. Attaching screenshot of the DOM structure from the dev tool for reference to the main question.

Comment: Sounds like you have some problems outside of the DOM snippet in the image, possibly including your main landmark.